# Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-arrayadapter

In my application i am trying to display latitude and longitude of multiple points on google map from coordinates stored in my sqllite database. Here is my Map.Class where i display the point.

```
public class Map extends MapActivity {
    private MapView map = null;
    private MyLocationOverlay me = null;
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
    boolean flag;

    public static Context context;

   ArrayList<Article> mArticles;

   EditText search;
   DBHelper helper;
   GeoPoint point;
   MapView mapView;
   Drawable marker;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.aproximite);

        helper = DBHelper.getInstance(this);// <= data from mysqllitedatabase

        map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

        map.getController().setCenter(getPoint(40.76793169992044, -73.98180484771729));
        map.getController().setZoom(17);
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mapOverlays = map.getOverlays();

        marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icone_sur_carte);
        marker.setBounds(0, 0, marker.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                marker.getIntrinsicHeight());

        map.getOverlays().add(new SitesOverlay(marker, map));//<===error occurance

        me = new MyLocationOverlay(this, map);
        map.getOverlays().add(me);


    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        me.enableCompass();
    }

    public MapView getMapView() {
        return this.map;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        me.disableCompass();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return (false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S) {
            map.setSatellite(!map.isSatellite());
            return (true);
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Z) {
            map.displayZoomControls(true);
            return (true);
        }

        return (super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event));
    }

    private GeoPoint getPoint(double lat, double lon) {
        return (new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1000000.0), (int) (lon * 1000000.0)));
    }

    private class SitesOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
        private List<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        private Drawable marker = null;
        private OverlayItem inDrag = null;
        private ImageView dragImage = null;
        private int xDragImageOffset = 0;
        private int yDragImageOffset = 0;
        private int xDragTouchOffset = 0;
        private int yDragTouchOffset = 0;
        private Context c;
        public int selectedIndex = -1;
        private final Bitmap bitMap;
        private View view = null;
        private boolean   isPinch  =  false;


        public SitesOverlay(Drawable marker, MapView mapView) {
            super(boundCenter(marker));
            this.marker = marker;
            c = mapView.getContext();
            dragImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.drag);
            xDragImageOffset = dragImage.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth() / 2;
            yDragImageOffset = dragImage.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

            mArticles = helper.getArticlesList();

            for (int i=0;i<mArticles.size();i++){



               double slat =Double.valueOf(mArticles.get(i).getLatitude().toString());
               double  vlong = Double.valueOf(mArticles.get(i).getLongitude().toString());

               GeoPoint pt = new GeoPoint((int) (slat * 1E6), (int) (vlong * 1E6));
                Log.e("lat long", "--- "+slat);
               // Map.mc.animateTo(pt);

                items.add(new OverlayItem(pt, mArticles.get(i).getNom().toString(), "Bendigo"));
                boundCenter(marker);


            }

            bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.icone_sur_carte);
            populate();
        }

        @Override
        protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
            return (items.get(i));
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

            boundCenterBottom(marker);
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return (items.size());
        }

        public void refresh() {
            populate();
        }

        public void clear() {
            items.clear();
            resetLastFocuesIndex();
        }

        public void resetLastFocuesIndex() {
            setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
            selectedIndex = -1;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean onTap(final int index) {
              if ( isPinch ){
                    return false;
              }else{

                /*  
                  getMapView().setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                    if (!items.isEmpty()) {
                        if (view != null) {
                            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        getMapView().invalidate();
                    }
                    }
                    getMapView().invalidate();
                    return true;
                }
            });*/

            if (view != null) {

                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                getMapView().removeView(view);
                getMapView().invalidate();
                flag = false;
                view = null;

            }

            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.balloon_overlay, null);
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.balloon_main_layout);
            layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.balloon_overlay_bg_selector);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.balloon_disclosure);
            TextView text = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.balloon_item_title);
            text.setText(items.get(index).getTitle());

            if (items.get(index).getTitle() != null
                    && items.get(index).getTitle().equals("Me") == false) {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icone_sur_carte);
            }

            Projection projection = getMapView().getProjection();
            Point point = new Point();
            projection.toPixels(items.get(index).getPoint(), point);

            int x = (int) (view.getWidth() / 2f);
            int y = -bitMap.getHeight() - 3;

            MapView.LayoutParams lp = new MapView.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, items.get(index)
                            .getPoint(), x, y,
                    MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER);
                    getMapView().removeView(view);
                    getMapView().invalidate();
                    getMapView().addView(view, lp);
                    getMapView().invalidate();

                view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (!items.isEmpty()) {
                            if (view != null) {
                                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                getMapView().invalidate();


                                System.out.println("SelectedIndex: "+selectedIndex);


                            }
                        }
                        getMapView().invalidate();
                    }
                });
                    selectedIndex = index;
                    return true;           
          }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {
            final int action = event.getAction();
            final int x = (int) event.getX();
            final int y = (int) event.getY();
            boolean result = false;

            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                for (OverlayItem item : items) {
                    Point p = new Point(0, 0);

                    map.getProjection().toPixels(item.getPoint(), p);

                    if (hitTest(item, marker, x - p.x, y - p.y)) {
                        result = true;
                        inDrag = item;
                        items.remove(inDrag);
                        populate();

                        xDragTouchOffset = 0;
                        yDragTouchOffset = 0;

                        setDragImagePosition(p.x, p.y);
                        dragImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        xDragTouchOffset = x - p.x;
                        yDragTouchOffset = y - p.y;
                        isPinch=false;
                        break;
                    }
                }


            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && inDrag != null) {

                if (view != null) {
                    if (view.getVisibility() != 0) {
                        Log.e("touch", " out move");
                        setDragImagePosition(x, y);
                        result = true;
                        isPinch=true;
                    }else{
                        setDragImagePosition(x, y);
                        isPinch=false;
                    }
                }else{
                    setDragImagePosition(x, y);
                    result = true;
                    isPinch=true;
                }

            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && inDrag != null) {
                dragImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                GeoPoint pt = map.getProjection().fromPixels(
                        x - xDragTouchOffset, y - yDragTouchOffset);
                OverlayItem toDrop = new OverlayItem(pt, inDrag.getTitle(),
                        inDrag.getSnippet());

                Log.e("touch", " out last" + pt.getLatitudeE6());
                items.add(toDrop);
                populate();
                inDrag = null;
                result = true;
                isPinch = false;
            }
                return (isPinch || super.onTouchEvent(event,mapView));
        }

        private void setDragImagePosition(int x, int y) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) dragImage.getLayoutParams();

            lp.setMargins(x - xDragImageOffset - xDragTouchOffset, y
                    - yDragImageOffset - yDragTouchOffset, 0, 0);
            dragImage.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    }



}
```

When i run this code my application force code and my log displays the following error.

```
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.TabSample}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.map.Map}: java.lang.NumberFormatException
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.map.Map}: java.lang.NumberFormatException
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1491)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:657)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:329)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at .TabSample.setProximite(TabSample.java:659)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at .TabSample.onCreate(TabSample.java:98)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    ... 11 more
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDblImpl(Native Method)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:283)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:318)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:356)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at .map.Map$SitesOverlay.<init>(Map.java:156)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at .map.Map.onCreate(Map.java:78)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
05-25 14:18:38.125: E/AndroidRuntime(11240):    ... 20 more
05-25 14:23:44.253: I/Process(11240): Sending signal. PID: 11240 SIG: 9
```

Also i want to know how to integrade a background service in Map.Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in logcat:

```
at .TabSample.setProximite(TabSample.java:659)
```

here you have NumberFormatException - probably conversion String -> Integer / Float is wrong. the best way is to use Debugger in Eclipse which shuld allow to step through this problem.

Comment: latitude and longitude are double for coordinates